# Generate a public key certificate signed by CA with OpenSSL

Tags: cryptography, certificate, openssl, digital-signature

I am working on a webservice that requires a signature in the sent and received messages. After sending a certificate request to the entity that will consume the webservice, they sent me (in addition to their public key) 3 certificate authority certificates and asked me to send them my public key certificate signed by the aforementioned CAs. The document they sent me to do the process uses IIS "Complete certificate request" to do this operation but I am on a Linux server using OpenSSL. Is there a way to do it using OpenSSL? (I am new to these concepts so please correct me if there is anything incorrect, thanks).

Answer (score 0):

Found an article that explains the process of creating a self-signed cert with OpenSSL for use with IIS and it also talks about configuring/creating a CA.

[Tutorial for OpenSSL](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/docs/openssl_iis_ssl_howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a CA chain like ROOT -> A -> B -> C . More then one certifcates are used for signing for a customer certificate. So to solve this problem look your application manual for certificate chaining.

Comment: In particular if they told you to use "Complete Cert Request" that means one of the certs they supplied IS "your cert signed by the [supplied] CAs [chain]". Depending on your OpenSSL application, usually you put these certs in a file identified as something more or less like SSLCertChain.

Comment: Hello @dave_thompson_085, as a matter of fact yes, in addition to the CA chain they sent my signed certificate. Do you have any idea how to proceed from there? As I have said earlier I've been thrown this issue without any previous knowledge in cryptography or the process of digital signing.